# saving website contacts on iCloud

Tags: php, icloud

Wondering if someone could give me some advice, I am building a CRM for a client, and one of their "like to haves" is that if they create a new contact they would like the contacts details be both stored in the database but also sync with there iphone/ipad address book.

The only way I can think of doing this is if iCloud offers an api, is this something that could be achieved, or are there any other solutions that maybe could help me.

The CRM is being built on PHP if that makes a difference.

Comment: I suspect iCloud doesn't have APIs for direct web access, but rather is meant more for integration directly within native apps. Interesting question, though. A quick google found this, which may be of help: [iCloud for Developers](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php)

Answer (score 2):

Use Google Contacts API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/ and set up Gmail as Exchange server on iOS device.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone supports calDAV (calendaring) and cardDAV (address book) protocols for shared calendaring and address book features.

PHP client implmentation as part of roundcube: http://www.crash-override.net/carddav.html

Open source calDAV and cardDAV implementation: http://www.davical.org/

Comment: As @kdvy already said iCloud uses standard calDAV and cardDAV protocols and should be therefore accessible by any third-party library. Although this may violate Apple's terms of service and is not guaranteed to be future-proof. There's a small helper [script](http://icloud.niftyside.com/) available to fetch the principal URL.